# how do operating systems differentiate files?

Tags: filesystems, operating-systems

I'm new in programming and computers. So here is my question:
When I double click for example .exe or .jpg file how does operating system know how to behave with that file? I mean, is the file extension the only thing that makes operating system behave differently with files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple answer.  But briefly:

- operating systems *and* applications both may use file *contents* or file *attributes* (such as name) to determine how to treat a file.
- Microsoft Windows uses file suffix (such as `.exe`) pervasively, but even for that, there are different binary formats for ".exe" files (corresponding to the resources they need).  To the casual end-user, there is no difference.  For some further discussion on differences between ".exe" files, see *[What's the difference between PE32+ and PE32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284351/whats-the-difference-between-pe32-and-pe32)*
- The actual behavior on Microsoft Windows is configurable, stored in the system registry.  The name for this is "file associations", and you can modify those via the file explorer, as detailed in *[Change the program that opens a type of file](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-file-open-program#1TC=windows-7)*
- On Unix-like systems, *applications* (rather than the *operating system*) are more likely to use the file naming convention (suffixes) for deciding how to treat a file.  For example, mailcap and MIME-types are used by most web browsers.  The question *[How to get list of programs which can open a particular file extension in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662334/how-to-get-list-of-programs-which-can-open-a-particular-file-extension-in-linux/30662633#30662633)* skims the surface of that aspect.
- On Unix-like systems, the operating system looks primarily at the file *content*, e.g., so-called "hash-bang" lines at the beginning of scripts and other text-files (see [Since I cant google this “#!” what exactly is it's use in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660110/since-i-cant-google-this-what-exactly-is-its-use-in-the-url/8660133#8660133)), as well as binary headers.  The [`file`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/file.1.html) program is useful for giving information about either.  Applications (such as `gzip` and `unzip`) which care about their binary formats also look at the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which operating system you are talking about.  But since you mentioned ".exe", I'll assume you are talking about some version of Microsoft Windows.  In windows (with some exceptions) the file extension is what's used to decide what to do with a file when you double-click it in Windows Explorer.